# Determing Mclaurin series for $\sqrt{1-z^2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Determine the Mclaurin series and the convergence radius for $\sqrt{1-z^2}$.

I tried to adapt the series $(1+z)^\alpha=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}
   {{\alpha}\choose {n}}z^n$.

$\sqrt{1-z^2}=1+\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}
   {{\frac{1}{2}}\choose {n}}z^n=1+\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}
  (-1)^n\frac{(2n-3)!}{2n!!}z^{2n}$.

The solution on the book is $1-\frac{z^2}{2}-\sum_\limits{n=2}^{\infty}
  \frac{(2n-3)!}{2n!!}z^{2n}$

**Question:**

What did I do wrong? Can someone help me solve the exercise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your answer seems to involve factorials of negative numbers.  The book's answer avoids this by starting with $n=2$.  The series should start $1-\frac12z^2 - \frac18z^4 - \frac1{16}z^6 - \frac{5}{128}z^8- \cdots$

Comment: @Henry The book's answer must adapt a series already known to the one asked as I attempted to do. I do not know if the author picked up the same series I did. Why do you think my answer is wrong? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @PeterForeman Sorry but I am not following. Could you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: This all entirely depends on how you define the factorial function and combination function for things other than positive integers.